# Looking for a way to search in a text box with only one letter and return only those where the letter searched for is the first letter of the string

Tags: ms-access

Using a form with a text box search and a subform displaying the results.
So far in the query I am using criteria:

`LIKE "*" & Forms![nameForm]![txtBoxName] & "*"`

This is great, but if you search for the letter A, you get names that start with A AND names that have an A in it somewhere. I want to return only names that START with A. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the first wildcard character from your criteria:

LIKE Forms![nameForm]![txtBoxName] & "*"

Comment: I tried this without removing the 1st & and got a syntax errors. Now i know that & is the syntax for concatenation in vba. Thanks.